# How to reset viewport scaling without full page refresh?

Tags: android, mobile-safari, viewport

I have a web-page that has the "user-scalable" attribute of the viewport meta tag set to true ([Safari reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/html/const/viewport), [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Metadata)).  So users with browsers that recognize the attribute (such as Mobile Safari, Android Browser) can pinch to scale the page.  However, there is a link that refreshes most of the page using AJAX, but does not perform a full page refresh.  I'd like to reset the viewport scaling to the initial value using JavaScript.  But I can't figure out how to do this.

The only solution seems to be a full page refresh.  Anyone know of a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple deal to set the viewport using jQuery:

```
$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
```

This works on Mobile Safari using jQuery Mobile as a framework.

Answer (score 0):

After loading the page most browsers will ignore changing the viewport. Opera will do it, Fennec and Android won't, if I remember my own tests with a faked body correctly.