# Can the viewport scale be reset without hard refresh?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, viewport

In mobile Safari (for example) if a user is on the full site and then switches to mobile, it persists the previous scale of the viewport.

How can I force the browser to do a one-time forgetting of the memorized scale?

I found this better-phrased question meant for android: [How to reset viewport scaling without full page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380385/how-to-reset-viewport-scaling-without-full-page-refresh)

But I am seeing the same problem on iOS too, without hard refresh page scale never resets.